# How to configure global charset on MySQL

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

I tried to change the charset for our MySQL via **my.cnf** and it failed.  I added the charset settings listed below:

```
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-locking
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M

# ------------- MYSQL CHARSETS --------------
character_set_system = utf8
character_set_server = utf8
character_set_results = utf8
character_set_database = utf8
character_set_connection = utf8
character_set_client = utf8

collation_connection = utf8_general_ci
collation_database = utf8_general_ci
collation_server = utf8_general_ci
```

When I had these enabled, MySQL failed to start.  How can I make sure everything defaults to utf8 - always?

**Update**

There are still a few places having issues in being UTF8

```
character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database  latin1
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    latin1
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
collation_connection    utf8_general_ci
collation_database  latin1_swedish_ci
collation_server    latin1_swedish_ci
```

Unfortunately I still haven't come up with a soluton... any ideas?

Currently I'm using this configuration successfully:

```
[mysqld]
default-character-set = utf8
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8


[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8
```

But PHPMyAdmin is still showing some latin1

```
character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database  latin1
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    latin1
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
collation_connection    utf8_general_ci
collation_database  latin1_swedish_ci
collation_server    latin1_swedish_ci
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to incorporate the following into your my.cnf file

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8


[mysqld]
default-character-set = utf8    
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

You can find more information on the following manual pages

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-configuration.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_system
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_server

In response to Mark's answer, if you need to convert existing tables/databases to the correct character set you will need a suitable `ALTER` query. Something similar to the below:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Alternatively there's a great PHP script [here](http://bogdan.org.ua/2008/02/08/convert-mysql-database-from-one-encodingcollation-into-another.html) which does it for you.

Comment: I've followed your instructions and checked the documentation links... still having a few issues (see ^)

Comment: Whenever I add `collation-server = utf8_general_ci` to the `mysqld` section mysql fails to restart

Comment: Can you look what's in the log file? It should give you an error message as to why it failed. I take it your mysqld was compiled with the utf8 general character set included?

Comment: Yes I think it was... which log file?

Comment: They're in various places- usually /var/log/. Which cos are you running? Look for mysql.log mysql.err anything in a mysql folder if it exists. Also look in /var/log/messages

Comment: This solution worked perfectly and completely for me. Thx

Comment: Works for me (Debian 8, MySQL 5.5), except for `default-character-set = utf8` line under `[mysqld]` section. Adding this very line results in mysqld taking forever to restart. Unicode support, however, works great even w/o this line.

Comment: 2016 update -- MySQL5.5 on Debian only requires `character-set-serve=utf8` and `collation-server=utf8_general_ci`

Comment: Good for Win7, MySQL 5.7, except `[mysqld] default-character-set=...` halt restart with an "unknown variable" error-event.

Answer (score 2):

Ben's answer is ok, but changing the settings will ABSOLUTELY NOT alter existing tables character sets or collations. Do that with an appropriate ALTER TABLE statement.

Note that if you don't specify it, tables are created in the database default character set. This is a per-database setting which can be adjusted with ALTER DATABASE. This is also not set in my.cnf.

Comment: New databases will inherit the default mysql settings though, right?